How to run WooCommerce HPOS sync again for previously synced orders?
I synced my orders with HPOS Sync via Woocommerce Settings > Advanced > Features page but didn’t switch to HPOS and did not check – Enable compatibility mode (synchronizes orders to the posts table) option.
Due to this, post & postmeta tables and HPOS tables are out of sync again as after initial sync, only postmeta and post tables were updated as compatibility mode was not enabled.
How to re-sync the previously synced orders that have become out of sync as postmeta was updated after initial sync?

How to re-sync legacy orders to High Performance Orders Storage
First, always make a database backup.
Go to WooCommerce Settings > Advanced > Features > Order data storage (section):
Enable only "WordPress posts storage (legacy)" option, and save.

Go to WooCommerce Status > Tools > Delete the custom orders tables (section):
Click on the delete button.

Go back to WooCommerce Settings > Advanced > Features > Order data storage (section):
Click on "Sync XXX pending orders" link

Then click on "Enable compatibility mode (synchronizes orders to the posts table)", and save.
Now the WooCommerce Action Scheduler will sync orders by batch, each hour.
Once done, you can switch to "High-performance order storage (recommended)" option and save.

I have over 1 million orders that are already synced and that took 5 days. TO avoid syncing again, I am creating a function to match orders in postmeta and hpos tables and want to sync only those orders that are not found in HPOS. Is there any way to sync individual orders by order id?

@dc09 To sync individual orders, just hit update button on the related admin edit order page… Or build your own function that uses the save() method on the related WC_Order object.

Just calling $order->save() will sync the order and all its meta, right?

@dc09 yes, normally it should. Try it and let me know.

Calling $order->save() works, thanks.
